# Como filtrar linhas em que as colunas cumprem condições consecutivamente no Python?

Tags: python, funções, pandas

Estou a tentar filtrar linhas em que as **colunas** cumpram ***condições consecutivamente***.
Isto é, se a linha tiver colunas com as condições de **após um L/I**, a coluna seguinte tenha um **A/S**, então que retorne o valor de `1` na nova coluna(caso não se verifique, retorne `0`)

Input:

```
       RFA RFB RFC RFD       
    0   S   S   S   S   
    1   A   I   A   A       
    2   A   A   L   A       
    4   S   S   L   A
```

Output:

```
       RFA RFB RFC RFD  promo
    0   S   S   S   S     0
    1   A   I   A   A     1 
    2   A   A   L   A     1
    4   S   S   L   A     1
```

Script:

```
      def promo_behaviour(x):
          for i in range(0,95411):
             for j in data_rfa_r.columns:
                 if (x[j][i] == 'L' or x[j][i] == 'I') and (x[j][i+1] == 'A' or x[j][i+1] == 'S'):
                    return 1
                 else:
                    return 0
      data_rfa_r['promo'] = data_rfa_r.apply(promo_behaviour)
```

Escrevi esta função mas sem sucesso (95411 são o número de observações/linhas).

Esqueci de referir que no contexto do problema, a coluna de index 0 é a mais recente! Ou seja, deve ser ***lido da direita para a esquerda***.

EDIT:

```
Output:
```

```
       RFA promo2 RFB promo1 RFC RFD    
    0   S    0    S     0     S   S   
    1   A    1    I     0     A   A     
    2   A    0    A     1     L   A   
    4   S    0    S     0     L   A
```

Comment: Boa tarde! Na base de dados real não! mas são mais de 25 variaveis( --> 25 colunas)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução em uma linha:

```
df['promo']=pd.Series([bool(re.search(r'(L|I)(?=[AS])',k)) for k in df.sum(axis=1)])
```

Minha ideia foi transformar as colunas em uma única coluna com a concatenação das outras colunas. Nessa nova coluna, apliquei o teste lógico usando regex. Usei positive lookbehind para verificar se existe um A ou S depois que vi um I ou L. Código inteiro:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df=pd.read_csv("stack.txt",sep=",")

df['promo']=pd.Series([bool(re.search(r'(L|I)(?=[AS])',k)) for k in df.sum(axis=1)]).map({True:1, False:0})

print(df)
```

Retorna:

```
  RFA RFB RFC RFD  promo
0   S   S   S   S      0
1   A   I   A   A      1
2   A   A   L   A      1
3   S   S   L   A      1
```

Comment: Apesar de achar que não vai funcionar no meu caso particular por causa de  missing values(null), acho que estaria completamente correcto!

Comment: bom, acho que basta substituir o NULL por qualquer string que não seja A,S,L ou I, não?

Comment: Numa outra situação seria, mas neste caso os null values são importantes pois na verdade não são null values(são simplesmente momentos em que o cliente ainda não era socio para ter acesso à promoção) Mas substituindo deve funcionar com certeza! Vou experimentar e caso funcione, colocarei como correcta também! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Ok. Evite o nested for loop pq é um algoritmo O(n^2) e, portanto, extremamente ineficiente.

Comment: Seguirei o seu conselho! Apesar da amostra serem só 100k mas mesmo assim, compensa sempre!

Comment: Após resolver denominar os null por outra letra...funcionou certinho com um tempo muito melhor! Já agora, por acaso sabe se dá para colocar a coluna promo quando se verifica  condição? Isto é, na promoção que fez ir o L para o A...vou colocar um edit!

Comment: Talvez seja o caso de abrir outra pergunta

Comment: Ok! Era só para evitar abrir outro tópico!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o isin, criando uma lista de possíveis combinações.

```
vl = ['LA','IA','LS','IS']
dados['promo'] = (dados.shift(axis = 1) + dados).isin(vl).any(axis = 1).astype(int)
```

1. `dados.shift` 'move' o data frame
2. `isin` verifica a ocorrência dentro da lista
3. `any` verifica se existe ocorrência de True nas linhas
4. `astype(int)` retorna 0 ou 1 no lugar de True ou False